# Generate property with attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is there any way in VS or Resharper to generate properties and **include** attributes above each property? Basically I am making a web service that requires a lot of members declared with [DataMember] and it would be nice to have it generate that when generating the property itself (when using resharper, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [Resharper templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html) is what you're looking for. You can create your own template for property with `[DataMember]` attribute and call it something like `propdata`.